# XamlParseException - Image Pixels Manipulation with WPF C# / Kinect

Tags: c#, image, kinect, pixel

I want to use this code to access the image pixels to be used with my Kinect code.. so i can replace the **depth bits** with the **Image bits**, so i created a WPF application and As soon as i run my code, i get this exception (it doesnt happen on a Console application) but i need this to run as a **WPF application** since . . i intend to use it with **Kinect**

**XamlParseException**

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'pixelManipulation.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position
>   '9'.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

           System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new
                System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"autumn_scene.jpg");


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            doSomethingWithBitmapFast(b);

        }

        public static void doSomethingWithBitmapFast(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                bmp.LockBits(rect,
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                    bmp.PixelFormat);

            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr,
                           rgbValues, 0, bytes);

            byte red = 0;
            byte green = 0;
            byte blue = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    //See the link above for an explanation 
                    //of this calculation (assumes 24bppRgb format)
                    int position = (y * bmpData.Stride) + (x * 3);
                    blue = rgbValues[position];
                    green = rgbValues[position + 1];
                    red = rgbValues[position + 2];
                    Console.WriteLine("Fast: " + red + " "
                                       + green + " " + blue);
                }
            }
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <Window x:Class="pixelManipulation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your xaml file not in your code. As exception states **xaml parse exception**. My guess is that you had some event handler / property declared in xaml to bind to something that no longer exists. Post xaml file content for more help.

**Edit**

So it is not what it seams to be. Xaml file is OK, But code is not. There is an exception thrown in constructor on line

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new
            System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"autumn_scene.jpg");
```

I'm not sure why this call to bitmap constructor is invalid but changing it to:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new Bitmap(
            System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"autumn_scene.jpg"));
```

should work fine.

Comment: <Window x:Class="pixelManipulation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>

Comment: I see some semicolons after xmlns declarations. Remove them and it should run.

Comment: There are no semi-colons . . i dont know why its showing here

Comment: I can copy the whole exception file here ..I mean Details

Comment: Have you tried to commenting out `doSomethingWithBitmapFast(b);` from constructor? I assume that xmlns statements also start with `http://` and it is not shown here? Is there an inner exception in your exception?

Comment: Commenting out the doSomethingWithBitmapFast(b) doesnt stop the exception .. and the Inner Expection says {"Parameter is not valid."}

Comment: You know what, I'm stunned. Try to crate new wpf windows project and just run it without modification.

Comment: Another idea! comment the 'new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"autumn_scene.jpg");'

Comment: Yes this is it. Now I know to ask for stack trace :)

Comment: Is your inner exception of type FileNotFoundException.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14162/discussion-between-rafal-and-sweta-dwivedi)